# liferay getting data from multiple tables from different portlets

Tags: mysql, liferay

i have a project in which i need to fetch data from different tables which are located in different portlets in a plugin project.

suppose we have two portlet A and portlet B, which have tables A1 and B1 respectively.
i want to fetch data from both portlets.

Can any one help?
I have read about custom sql query ...http://www.liferaysavvy.com/2013/02/getting-data-from-multiple-tables-in.html

but still cant find a proper solution....

Comment: how are you accessing this tables in each plugin? are you using service-builder?

Comment: Yes..i am using service builder

Answer (score 0):

A good habit is using the **separately** portlet and service-portlet (model). Depends on how the project is extensive and what a build tool you are using (ant, maven) I think, that advantage is that you have implementation of the operations to DB **visible for anyone plugin** (common JAR file in lib directory and portlet-service in webapps) in portlet project.

More about the service-builder >> [Service-builder](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/6-2/service-builder)
<<

Comment: But i didn't get u ..What u are trying to say??..Please Elaborate